# Running Lua scripts using FastCGI

Tags: lua, nginx, fastcgi, lighttpd

I am currently trying to figure out ways to run Lua scripts using FastCGI with either lighttpd or Nginx. The only thing I was able to dig up yet was [WSAPI](http://keplerproject.github.com/wsapi/) of the Kepler project. But I wonder if there are other possibilities. Important for me is:

- should be as lightweight as possible
- should be stable enough to use in a production environment

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you end up using?

Comment: @CodeClown i used luafcgid, see answer below ... but that's long time ago. i did not do much with lua (at least not for web development) for years now, so maybe there's something better nowadays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend taking a look at this project:
http://github.com/STPeters/luafcgid

There are instructions on how to use it with nginx.