# Lua with Lighttpd on OpenWRT

Tags: lua, lighttpd, openwrt

I need to be able to execute Lua scripts to implement a REST API under Lighttpd web server running on OpenWRT.

Initially, I thought this could be done with mod_magnet which I got "working" but we need to support POST requests and believe mod_magnet cannot be used with POST requests.

I'd prefer not to use CGI as the overhead is too much per request; however, a FastCGI solution would be acceptable.

How can I invoke a Lua script to handle GET and POST requests under Lighttpd running on OpenWRT?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Lua scripts using FastCGI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063745/running-lua-scripts-using-fastcgi)

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Docs ModFastCGI](https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModFastCGI),

> lighttpd provides an interface to external programs that support the FastCGI interface. The FastCGI Interface is defined by http://www.fastcgi.com/ and is a platform-independent and server-independent interface between a web-application and a webserver.
>
> This means that FastCGI programs that run with the Apache webserver will run seamlessly with lighttpd and vice versa.

```
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )
```

-or-

```
include "conf.d/fastcgi.conf"
```